# Using angularjs JSONP when callback cant be defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp

I'm attempting to use Angularjs to gather data from the USGS Earthquake feed. Typically you would need to tack ?callback=JSON_CALLBACK on to the end of the URL for Angular to use it, however the USGS feed does not recognize this option.

The URL I'm using is http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojsonp and adding ?callback=JSON_CALLBACK (eg. http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojsonp?callback=JSON_CALLBACK) returns a dataset wrapped in a function called eqfeed_callback.

Is there any way to use this data? I've got an eqfeed_callback function but it's not in scope which makes using Angular pointless.

Here's the code that I've got as it stands:

```
function QuakeCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.get_quakes = function() {
        var url = 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojsonp';
        $http.jsonp(url)
    }

}

function eqfeed_callback(data) {
    return data;
}
```

Is there any way to either get the data back into the scope, or get angular to use the eqfeed_callback function internally?

Comment: Are you adverse to just using `JSON`? I hazarded a guess that removing the `p` from the url would make it just pure `JSON`, and it does.

Comment: That would work, however the USGS does not have CORS enabled so I get cross origin errors. Is there a way to use JSON if CORS isn't enabled? My understanding is that is a server side setting and not something I can modify.

Comment: Oh :/ guess you can't do that then; yes, it is a server side setting.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another option would be defining the eqfeed_callback within the scope like this:

```
function QuakeCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = null;
    $scope.get_quakes = function() {
      var url = 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojsonp';
      $http.jsonp(url)
    }

    window.eqfeed_callback = function(data) {
      $scope.data = data
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! That does it. Thanks!

Comment: Or even: `$window.eqfeed_callback ... `

Comment: That's just another way of using a global.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so true, but I think it keeps the logic more in place :)

Answer (score 0):

The only idea that comes to mind is (blech) to use a global, and then to manually trigger an Angular update, e.g.:

```
var callback$scope;
function QuakeCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.get_quakes = function() {
        var url = 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojsonp';
        callback$scope = $scope;
        $http.jsonp(url)
    }

}

function eqfeed_callback(data) {
    if (callback$scope) {
        // 1. Use callback$scope here
        // 2. Set callback$scope to undefined or null
        // 3. Trigger an Angular update (since it won't be automatic)
    }
}
```

Not pretty, but...

Comment: He could just use a `JSON` instead of `JSONP` request, which would be a little less sketchy than this. Also, wouldn't it need to be `$scope = callback$scope`? Or even `$http.jsonp.call(callback$scope, [url])`?

Comment: @Fred: He can't use JSON because to do that, he'd have to use ajax, and that would be a cross-origin request. The SOP won't allow that (unless, of course, the earthquake.usgs.gov supports CORS and the user is using a browser that supports it, and he handles the whole IE9 and earlier problem).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @MichaelVanRijn's answer:

In order to keep the "global peace", define the global function when you need it and nullify it right after.

```
.controller('QuakeCtrl', function($window, $scope, $http) {
  $scope.get_quakes = function() {
    $window.eqfeed_callback = function(data){
      console.log("quake data", data)
    };

    // load your jsonp data
    $http.jsonp('http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojsonp')
    .then(function(success) {
      console.log(success);
      $window.eqfeed_callback = null;
    }, function(fail) {
      console.log(fail);
      $window.eqfeed_callback = null;
    })
  }
})
```