# Angular Service JSONP Request with Custom Callback

Tags: angularjs, jsonp, angular-services

I'm pulling from JSONP feeds that have custom callback functions, [for example](http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/json/json-as2015.js):

```
jsonpCallbackAllStar2015({
    "events": [
        {
            "title": "XYZ"
        }
        ...
    ]
})
```

I'm able to do this, using the [solution posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19375248/1179207) like so:

```
var jsonUrl = 'http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/json/json-as2015.js?callback=JSON_CALLBACK' + (new Date().getTime());

$http.jsonp(jsonUrl);

window.jsonpCallbackAllStar2015 = function(data) {
    $scope.events = data.events;
}
```

However I would now like to do this in a service so that I can load the data one time and inject it into all of my controllers. When I try this, however, I get an [$injector undefined](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/undef) error, which I'm guessing is because the service doesn't return fast enough:

```
eventsFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
function eventsFactory($http) {
    var jsonUrl = 'http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/json/json-as2015.js?callback=JSON_CALLBACK' + (new Date().getTime());

    $http.jsonp(jsonUrl);

    window.jsonpCallbackAllStar2015 = function(data) {
        return data.events;
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to fix this or will I have to repeat the jsonp request in each controller? [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbhn84ea/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not a beautiful solution this should work for you. I added in some very basic caching. I haven't used jsonp in angular and it seems that setting the cache in the $http config doesn't work. It would have been a better option.

```
app.factory('eventsFactory', [ '$http', '$q', 
    function( $http, $q ) {

        var pub = {};

        var jsonUrl = 'http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/json/json-as2015.js?callback=JSON_CALLBACK' + (new Date().getTime()),
            cachedResponse;

        pub.getEvent = function() {

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            if ( cachedResponse ) {
                deferred.resolve( cachedResponse );
            }

            else {

                $http.jsonp( jsonUrl );

                window.jsonpCallbackAllStar2015 = function( data ) {
                    cachedResponse = data;
                    deferred.resolve( data );
                }

            }

            return deferred.promise;

        };

        return pub;

    }
]);
```

Now inside of your controller you can do this:

```
app.controller('someController', [ 'eventsFactory', 
    function( eventsFactory) {

        eventsFactory.getEvent().then(function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        });

    }
]);
```

Comment: do you have any idea how to do this in the latest version of angular? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dgcqtd?file=src/app/geolocation.service.ts