# Angular Promise Called Twice is Only Deferring to First Caller

Tags: angularjs, jsonp, deferred, angular-promise, angular-services

I'm working on a video series app that's set up like so:

```
angular.module('videoSeries', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router'])
  .config(config)
  .factory('episodes', episodesFactory)
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
  .controller('EpisodeCtrl', EpisodeCtrl);
```

The factory 'episodes' loads a JSONP file that both controllers need to read from. In order to ensure that the controllers wait until the JSONP has successfully returned, I set up a promise in the factory like so ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755469/angular-service-jsonp-request-with-custom-callback)):

```
episodesFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
function episodesFactory($http, $q) {
  var pub = {},
      jsonUrl = 'http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/json/json-wgtv.js?callback=JSON_CALLBACK' + (new Date().getTime()),
      cachedResponse;

  pub.getData = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if (cachedResponse) {
      deferred.resolve(cachedResponse);
    }

    else {
      $http.jsonp(jsonUrl);

      window.jsonCallbackWGTV = function(data) {
        cachedResponse = data;
        deferred.resolve(data);
      }
    }

    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return pub;
}
```

And then both of the controllers execute after the .then returns like so:

```
MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'episodes'];
function MainCtrl($scope, episodes) {
  episodes.getData().then(function(data) {
    $scope.episodes = data.episodes;
  });
}

EpisodeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'episodes'];
function EpisodeCtrl($scope, $stateParams, episodes) {
  episodes.getData().then(function(data) {
    $scope.episode = data.episodes[$stateParams.episodeIndex];
  });
}
```

This works fine if only one controller calls .getData() at a time, but if both call it simultaneously (which happens if you load directly into the episodes state), it looks like one promise is forgotten.

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qTR5I0m3YyctOYH8sosI?p=preview). Note that in order to see the issue, you click on an episode and then reload directly to that route, but I'm not sure how to do that in plunkers since the URL doesn't update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to sidestep the issue by using a resolve in your root state.  All children states will inherit the resolved data.

```
.state('root', {
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      'episodesList': {
        templateUrl: '/episodelist.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      }
    },
    resolve: {
        'cachedEpisodes': ['episodes', function(episodes){
            return episodes.getData();
        }]
    }
  }
```

In this case the resolve should only occur once when any child state activates this root state.

Edit:
You don't need to include the episodes factory in the config.  A state resolve is an object map.  Each key is a name that will be available in the injections for any controllers or child controllers under that state.

The resolve function will not get executed until the state becomes active, at this point it will have access to all of the runtime (not config) injectables.

It may look a little strange that I'm wrapping the function in an array.  Each value of the array is the name of an injectable and the final value of the array must be the function into which they are injected.  This is enabled in angular to help prevent problems with optimizers that mangle argument names (which otherwise would be used to determine the injectable).

Oh, also any resolve functions which return promises will be fully resolved by angular before the route change is completed and their resolved value is what is injected into the controllers.

```
MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'cachedEpisodes'];
function MainCtrl($scope, data) {
  $scope.episodes = data.episodes;
}

EpisodeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'cachedEpisodes'];
function EpisodeCtrl($scope, $stateParams, data) {
  var i = 0, len = data.episodes.length, episode;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (data.episodes[i].season === $stateParams.season && data.episodes[i].episode === $stateParams.episode) {
      episode = data.episodes[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  $scope.episode = episode;
}
```

Comment: could you include a little more code? does 'episodes' have to be injected into config() for this to work? and do the controllers still have to include 'episodes' or would they now include 'cachedEpisodes'? also, are you working with my promise code, or incorporating @Roamer-1888's changes? sorry, not very familiar with resolve, i really appreciate the help

Comment: thanks for adding more info, that is all very helpful. however, now the main page is blank, getData() doesn't ever seem to be getting called: http://plnkr.co/edit/AGR90r4zJHzk4jfch2Uq?p=preview

Comment: Getting any error messages?  What's the value of the cachedEpisodes in the main controller?  Can't see the plnkr at the moment, on a mobile device

Comment: no error messages when i run it locally and it's never reaching the main controller :(

Comment: Ah, I see the error.  Sorry, silly mistake.  I forgot to put the 'episodes' argument into the resolve function.  I'll edit the answer

Comment: ah k, well it's back to showing up, but still loading directly to an episode page doesn't work, here is the code if you want to take a look locally: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dy9pp2ycxbhffh0/video-series.zip?dl=0

Comment: Hmm, you're selecting an episode using the ui-sref tag in the html and providing an episodeIndex value in the stateparams, but you don't have any way to get that value through the url.  So if you load the episode url directly the 'episodeIndex' value is null.

Comment: @dougmacklin See new edit.  I changed the episode controller to identify the episode by the season and episode number instead of by an index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72986/discussion-between-dougmacklin-and-scott-vickers).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is fundamentally caused by the remote resource *always* returning its data wrapped in `jsonCallbackWGTV() {...}`, causing your two simultaneous calls to vie for `window.jsonCallbackWGTV()`. and *he who laughs last, laughs loudest*.

JSONP resources should really allow the callback's name to be specified by the client, but that is presumably out of your control.

The problem should be overcome by caching your deferred rather than the data delivered to it. Thus, the original `.getData()` call and all subsequent calls can return a promise derived from the same deferred.

```
episodesFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
function episodesFactory($http, $q) {
    var jsonUrl = 'http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/.element/media/2.0/teamsites/warriors/json/json-wgtv.js',
    deferred;
    return {
        getData: function() {
            if (!deferred) {
                deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.jsonp(jsonUrl);
                window.jsonCallbackWGTV = function(data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                    delete window.jsonCallbackWGTV;
                }
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
}
```

More typically, you would cache the deferred's promise rather than the deferred itself but the `jsonCallbackWGTV` issue makes it necessary to keep a reference to the deferred anyway, and the cached deferred might as well be used for both purposes.

Comment: thanks @Roamer-1888, while everything you said makes sense, the issue is still occurring. individual episodes still fail to load if you go straight to one (title and desc don't show up) rather than starting out at the homepage, while the list of episodes still loads correctly

Comment: Can only think something else is going on. Must confess, I'm out of ideas right now.